# how to read style="display: block; element value using x-path in selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Kindly help me to read Text of the element which I'm trying to access using x-path (I tried absolute and partial x-path but could not able to read value. below is my code. Getting message -"INFO: Detected dialect: W3C"

```
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class xpathPractice {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\BrowserDriver\\geckodriver.exe");

            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.get("http://www.lavasa.com/learn/acca.aspx");
            String str3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-nav']/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a")).getText();
            System.out.println(str3);

            //After executing this code, I see the line in console as "INFO: Detected dialect: W3C"

        }
    }
```

Comment: What exact output you want to get?

Comment: Please also include the HTML of a sample page (or a portion of a sample page) that you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

the element you are trying to find is actually hidden, which is revealed on mouseover. So, we'll have to first make the web element visible, only then you can use the **getText()** function.

**Step 1**: Identify the web element you want to mouseover:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main-nav']/ul/li[4]/a"));
```

**Step 2**: Use the Actions Class to moverover the webelement:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(ele);
act.build().perform();
```

**Step 3**: Now, once the element is visble, go ahead and use getText() to get the text of the element.

```
 String str3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-nav']/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a")).getText();
 System.out.println(str3);
```

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, please mark "Accept as Answer".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to gettext from a webelement which is not displaying on the current screen.

We can getText by two ways.

1. Using Javascript executor

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\BrowserDriver\\geckodriver.exe");

   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   driver.get("http://www.lavasa.com/learn/acca.aspx");
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-nav']/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a"));
   String script =(String)js.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;",element);
   System.out.println(script);
   ```

2.Using actions mouse hover the element and then use getText.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use `getAttribute()` method of selenium as follows:

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-nav']/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```